# value.forEach is not a function on web3 send

Tags: solidity, web3js, metamask

I try to call a smart contract method in my web page, this is my following code:

```
this.miniVaultContract.methods.addDocument("0x00aaff","0x00aaff","0x00aaff",["0x00aaff", "0x00aaff", "0x00aaff"],[1, 2, 3],4,2,3,1)
.send({
    from: this.selectedAccount //My Metamask address
}).on('error', error => {
    alert("An error has occured when adding your document (ERR: " + error + ")");
    return;
});
```

My smart contract looks like this:

```
function addDocument(
    bytes32 documentId, bytes32 title, bytes32 description, bytes32[] keywords, uint[] ratings, uint documentType, uint startDate, uint endDate, uint duration
)
    public
    returns (bool)
{
    /* my code */
}
```

When I try to call the method, I get the following error:

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): value.forEach is not a function

I thought maybe it has to do with the array in the parameters, but I can't seem to find any documentation about that in web3.

Any ideas on what could go wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Try and do the following.

```
this.miniVaultContract.methods.addDocument("0x00aaff","0x00aaff","0x00aaff",[["0x00aaff", "0x00aaff", "0x00aaff"]],[[1, 2, 3]],4,2,3,1)
.send({
    from: this.selectedAccount //My Metamask address
}).on('error', error => {
    alert("An error has occured when adding your document (ERR: " + error + ")");
    return;
});
```